# How to add confidence intervals around predicted prior probabilities of latent class membership in a LCA model fitted with {poLCA}?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add confidence intervals to the predicted prior probabilities from a latent class analysis (LCA) model with covariates.

I have prepared an example built upon one provided by the authors of the package {poLCA} ([link](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v042i10)).

The relevant piece for calculating the confidence intervals should be the covariance matrix in the object with the fitted model (`nes.3cov$coeff.V` in this example).

The solution should add the lower and upper bounds from the confidence intervals to the object `pdata`, so they can be included as ribbons in the visualization.

```r
library(poLCA)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data(election)

## Fit LCA model with covariates using 3 classes
f.3cov <- cbind(MORALG,CARESG,KNOWG,LEADG,DISHONG,INTELG,
                MORALB,CARESB,KNOWB,LEADB,DISHONB,INTELB)~PARTY*AGE
nes.3cov <- poLCA(f.3cov,election,nclass=3)          # log-likelihood: -16135.39 

probs.start <- poLCA.reorder(nes.3cov$probs.start,
                             order(nes.3cov$P,decreasing=TRUE))
nes.3cov <- poLCA(f.3cov,election,nclass=3,probs.start=probs.start)

# Create profiles for predicted prior probabilities
## Strong dems and strong reps of different age
pred.profs <- rbind(cbind(1,1,c(18:80),(c(18:80)*1)),
                 cbind(1,7,c(18:80),(c(18:80)*7)))
exb.pred.profs <- exp(pred.profs %*% nes.3cov$coeff)

# Calculate predicted prior probabilities
pred.profs <- cbind(1, exb.pred.profs)/(1 + rowSums(exb.pred.profs))
pdata <- cbind(data.frame(pred.profs),
                    age = rep(18:80, 2),
                    party = rep(c("Strong Democrat", "Strong Republican"), 
                                each = 63))
# Prepare data for plot
pdata <- pdata |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = X1:X3, names_to = "affinity", values_to = "pp") |> 
  mutate(affinity = case_when(
    affinity == "X1" ~ "Other",
    affinity == "X2" ~ "Bush affinity",
    affinity == "X3" ~ "Gore affinity"))
  
# Plot predicted prior probabilities
pdata |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = pp, fill = affinity, linetype = affinity)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("longdash", "dotted", "solid")) +
  facet_wrap(~ party) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1)) +
  labs(x = "Age", y = "Probability of latent class membership") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a pseudo-Bayesian approach, treating the coefficients as posterior means and the variance-covariance matrix as the posterior variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients.  Then, you take random draws from the multivariate normal distribution with the coefficients and variance-covariance matrix as parameters (I did 2500).  For each draw you make the matrix of probabilities.  Then, you can find the lower and upper bounds from those 2500 simulations.

#### Estimate models

```r
library(poLCA)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data(election)

## Fit LCA model with covariates using 3 classes
f.3cov <- cbind(MORALG,CARESG,KNOWG,LEADG,DISHONG,INTELG,
                MORALB,CARESB,KNOWB,LEADB,DISHONB,INTELB)~PARTY*AGE
nes.3cov <- poLCA(f.3cov,election,nclass=3) 
probs.start <- poLCA.reorder(nes.3cov$probs.start,
                             order(nes.3cov$P,decreasing=TRUE))
nes.3cov <- poLCA(f.3cov,election,nclass=3,probs.start=probs.start)
```

#### Calculate probabilties

```r
pred.profs <- rbind(cbind(1,1,c(18:80),(c(18:80)*1)),
                    cbind(1,7,c(18:80),(c(18:80)*7)))
q <- cbind(1, exp(pred.profs %*% nes.3cov$coeff))
p <- prop.table(q, 1)
```

#### Do simulation

```r
B <- MASS::mvrnorm(2500, c(nes.3cov$coeff), nes.3cov$coeff.V)
B <- lapply(1:nrow(B), \(i)matrix(B[i, ], ncol=2))
probs <- lapply(B, function(b){
  q <- cbind(1, exp(pred.profs %*% b))
  prop.table(q, 1)
})
probs <- abind::abind(probs, along=3)
lwr <- apply(probs, c(1,2), quantile, .025)
upr <- apply(probs, c(1,2), quantile, .975)
colnames(p) <- paste0("pp_", 1:3)
colnames(lwr) <- paste0("lwr_", 1:3)
colnames(upr) <- paste0("upr_", 1:3)
```

#### Combine probabilities, lower and upper bounds and data

```r
pdata <- cbind(data.frame(p),
               data.frame(lwr), 
               data.frame(upr), 
               age = rep(18:80, 2),
               party = rep(c("Strong Democrat", "Strong Republican"), 
                           each = 63))
# Prepare data for plot
pdata <- pdata |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:9, names_sep="_", names_to = c(".value", "affinity")) |> 
  mutate(affinity = case_when(
    affinity == "1" ~ "Other",
    affinity == "2" ~ "Bush affinity",
    affinity == "3" ~ "Gore affinity"))
```

#### Make plot

```r
pdata |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = pp, ymin =lwr, ymax=upr, linetype = affinity)) +
  geom_ribbon(alpha=.2, fill="gray75") + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("longdash", "dotted", "solid")) +
  facet_wrap(~ party) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1)) +
  labs(x = "Age", y = "Probability of latent class membership") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Great, this looks as a good pragmatic solution. I would still like to find an answer that can provide the analytical solution or one that does not assume the pseudo Bayesian approach.